# Compare text in columns to create match flag

Tags: r

Have one data set with the responses to a survey. Trying to compare the item responses to the master answers. All of the columns are the full text value, and I want to create a flag where it matches the text to the master row and then creates a flag to dichotomize the Item response. I have seen the code for integers, but not for text. I have about 25 columns, example for simplicity:

Have:

```
Chart 1 user    Assistive device needed Assistance needed with 1 or more ADLs   Oriented    < 24 hours/day  One hour or less if at least one of the disciplines None    None
Chart 1 user    Assistive device needed Assistance needed with 1 or more ADLs   Oriented    < 24 hours/day  One hour or less if at least one of the disciplines None    None
Chart 2 user    Assistive device needed Independent Oriented    No capable caregiver availability   One hour or less if at least one of the disciplines None    None
Chart 2 user    Assistive device needed Independent Oriented    < 24 hours/day  One hour or less if at least one of the disciplines None    None
Chart 2 user    Assistive device needed Assistance needed with 1 or more ADLs   Oriented    < 24 hours/day  One hour or less if at least one of the disciplines None    None
Chart 1 expert  Assistive device needed Assistance needed with 1 or more ADLs   Oriented    < 24 hours/day  One hour or less if at least one of the disciplines None    None
Chart 2 expert  Assistive device needed Assistance needed with 1 or more ADLs   Oriented    < 24 hours/day  One hour or less if at least one of the disciplines None    None
```

Want to output a data frame like this:

```
Chart 1 user    1   1   1   1   1   1   1
Chart 1 user    1   1   1   1   1   1   1
Chart 2 user    1   0   1   0   1   1   1
Chart 2 user    1   0   1   1   1   1   1
Chart 2 user    1   1   1   1   1   1   1
```

Code currently:

```
amb_flg <- ifelse(c[,3] == "Assistive device needed",1,0)
adl_flg <- ifelse(c[,4] == "Assistance needed with 1 or more ADLs",1,0) 
cog_flg <- ifelse(c[,5] == "Oriented",1,0)
cgv_flg <- ifelse(c[,6] == "< 24 hours/day",1,0)
tim_flg <- ifelse(c[,7] == "One hour or less if at least one of the disciplines",1,0)
```

The problem with the above is that I would have to hard code the answers for each chart (1 vs 2). For efficiency, I want to create a function that produces a flag for if the value corresponds with the master value. Experimental code:

```
 ## Create agreement score
f.a <- function (a) {
    y <- subset(c, c$user == 'expert')
    z <- subset(c, c$user != 'expert')
    df <- apply(z, 2, function(b){
        for (i in y)
          ifelse(i %in% z, 1, 0)
    })
    return(as.data.frame(df))
}
df <- f.a(c)
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean something along these lines?  If you want to identify the Master answer algorithmically, that is much more complex.

```
> df <- data.frame(Name = c("Jim", "John", "Amy", "Master"),
+                  Item1 = c("Does agree", "Does not agree", "Does agree", "Does not agree"))
> df
    Name          Item1
1    Jim     Does agree
2   John Does not agree
3    Amy     Does agree
4 Master Does not agree

> df$Item1_flag <- ifelse(df$Item1 == "Does not agree", "expert", "not expert")
> df$Item1_count <- ifelse(df$Item1 == "Does not agree", "1", "0")
> df
    Name          Item1 Item1_flag Item1_count
1    Jim     Does agree not expert           0
2   John Does not agree     expert           1
3    Amy     Does agree not expert           0
4 Master Does not agree     expert           1
```

Comment: Similar. But with so many columns, I would rather write a function that checks each column between the two subset data frames and output a new column value in the final data frame.